# Google map is not displaying on bootstrap modal popup

Tags: google-maps, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

map is not displaying on bootstrap modal popup.

Modal popup is coming with blank page, How to display a map inside it. I added all the scripts files and css files. Help me out!

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Google Maps</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:auto; height: 400px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
// button 
<td><a href="#" onclick="loadMap('@callinfo.latitude','@callinfo.longitude')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a></td>
```

JS

```
<script>
    function loadMap(lat, lon) {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    }

    //show map on modal
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (lat, lon) {     
    loadMap(lat, lon);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the `onclick` attr from the a element.

The `loadMap` method should only run once, and this will be done from the `shown.bs.modal` event.

But this event function does not take the `lat` & `lon` as arguments.

Add `lat` & `lon` as data attributes on some element, for example the `map_canvas` div:

```
<div id="map_canvas" data-lat="@callinfo.latitude" data-lon="@callinfo.longitude" style="width:auto; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Then retrieve these values in the `shown.bs.modal` event like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {     
    loadMap($("#map_canvas").attr("data-lat"), $("#map_canvas").attr("data-lon"));
});
```